# Relationship between the positive definite matrix and matrix with negative eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

If $Q\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ (not necessarily symmetric) is positive semi-definite means for all $x\in\mathbb R^n$, 
$$
x Qx^T\ge0.
$$
Can I have the following result?

If the eigenvalues of matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ are all negative, and we have $W\in\mathbb S^n$ such that
$$
AW\succeq 0\quad (\text{AW is positive semi-definite})\\
WA^T\succeq 0\quad (\text{$WA^T$ is positive semi-definite})
$$

Can I claim that $W$ is negative semi-definite?

Comment: Just to be clear: your definition of positive semi-definite does *not* require the matrix to be symmetric?

Comment: Yes. the definition does not require the matrix to be symmetric